# Ordering the 'fill' of a stacked bar chart ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, fill, stacked-chart

Is there a way for me to order my stacked barchart by the variable The_Number_Of_Evaders rather than having to manually input the levels I would like?
[image: The current results of the graph can be found here]

```
The_Number_Of_Evaders <- c(287, 76, 237, 44, 249, 149, 3)

The_Results_Of_Using_The_Line <- c('Allied servicemen reached Spain through the Pyrenees', 'Civilians reached Spain through the Pyrenees',
 'Airmen who were arrested during their evasion', 'Airmen who were handed over to other evasion lines',
 'Airmen who were kept in camps of the "Operation Marathon" in France and Belgium', 
 'Airmen who were hidden by their lodgers until Liberation', 
 'Airmen who were killed during their evasion')

Line <- rep("Comete", 7)

Comete_Line <- data.frame(The_Number_Of_Evaders, The_Results_Of_Using_The_Line, Line)

Comete_Line_Ordered <- Comete_Line[order(Comete_Line$The_Number_Of_Evaders),]

Comete_Line_Ordered %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Line, y = The_Number_Of_Evaders, fill = The_Results_Of_Using_The_Line)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of this options. You can use `reorder()` with `fill`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Code 1
Comete_Line %>% ggplot(aes(x = Line,
                           y = The_Number_Of_Evaders,
                           fill = reorder(The_Results_Of_Using_The_Line,-The_Number_Of_Evaders))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5)+
  labs(fill='Var')
```

Output:

[image]

Or this:

```
#Code 2
Comete_Line %>% ggplot(aes(x = Line,
                           y = The_Number_Of_Evaders,
                           fill = reorder(The_Results_Of_Using_The_Line,The_Number_Of_Evaders))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5)+
  labs(fill='Var')
```

Output:

[image]